# MVC - Update view after long running tasks

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to display results of long running tasks and still have responsive web site. I am calculating several results and each calculation takes from few seconds to more than 10 seconds. If I put everything in controller the site will be dead for 10 - 20 seconds and then results will be displayed in view.

Rather than this I would like to immediately display a view and start with calculations. After each calculation is finished, the site should be updated (or at least status should be updated and results can be displayed at the end). It would be great if all calculations could run in parallel.

How can I implement this? Is there a sample that is already available?

PS: I have seen several web sites where you search for results (for instance airplane tickets) where site is updating during the search. Maybe this is similar.

Comment: Are you asking about how to design the UI, or how to technically solve the problem of notifying the user that their processing is complete?

Answer (score 0):

You can use asynchronous methods and controllers instead of the default synchronous ones.  Assuming you're talking about asp.net mvc, you could start by looking here http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4 and here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs11trainingcourse_aspnetmvc4_topic5.aspx

Hope that helps, lemme know if not.